# jQuery - Checked or unchecked value? Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if check box is checked in this example (javascript/jQuery.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391084/how-to-check-if-check-box-is-checked-in-this-example-javascript-jquery)

I've ran into a problem with my checkboxes. I'm trying to set off an event if the button is clicked differing the action whether it is checked or not checked.

Here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.pointBox').click(function(event){
    var operator = $(this).find('input').attr('operator');
    var pointNum = parseInt($(this).find('input').val());
    var pointsFromHtml = $('#newPoints').val();
    var currentPoints;
    var newPoints;

    if(pointsFromHtml.charAt(0) == '+'){
        currentPoints = parseInt(pointsFromHtml.substring(1));
    } else {
        return;
    }

    switch(operator){

        case 'addition':
            if(!$(this).attr('checked')){
                newPoints = currentPoints + pointNum;
            }
            if($(this).attr('checked')){
                alert();
                newPoints = currentPoints - pointNum;
            }
            break;
        case 'subtraction':
            newPoints = currentPoints - pointNum;
            break;
    }

    $('#futurePoints').text('+' + newPoints);
    $('#newPoints').attr('value', newPoints);

});

});
```

Comment: is there a form that submits the points or something?

Comment: What problem exactly did you run into? It's not very obvious from the code you've posted... Are you getting any errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: What is the problem? Have you tried to check what `$(this).attr('checked')` returns? Possibly $(this).is(':checked') will help.

Comment: The problem is it only recognizes when a box is checked. Not unchecked :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for being unclear.. I figured out how to solve the problem.

By changing the operator value when the button is clicked, to subtraction it fixes the problem so that it's next click will reduce the points. This more than likely won't help anyone else.. but it did solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the problem is the if statement isn't working, I have had success with

```
    if($("#something").is(":checked")){
//do something
}
```

And just in case, for unchecked go with

```
is(":not(:checked)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.checked` instead.

```
newPoints = this.checked ? currentPoints - pointNum
                         : currentPoints + pointNum;
```

Comment: That doesn't work :\ It will not set off my alert

Comment: Yes, it'll work. If you want to show your alert add the code after/before the code I provided.

Comment: It still only recognizes checked clicks, and registers every click as a check.